# Cropping a NumPy array of an arbitrary dimension given two corners

Tags: python, numpy

There are several posts for slicing 2D and 3D NumPy arrays, but in my program dimension of the array is not known. Consider a NumPy ndarray `A` of arbitrary dimension `n` (positive integer), and shape `D=[d1,...,dn]` (`di`s nonnegative integers), For example:

```
import numpy as np

D=np.array([2,3,4,5])

A=np.random.rand(*D)
```

Now I need to extract a block of `A` starting from `D1=[d11,...,d1n]` to `D2=[d21,...,d2n]`, where for all `0<i<=n  : 0<=d1i<=d2i<=di` . Something like:

```
A[D1:D2]
```

If I new `n` then I could simple use `A[d11:d21,...,d1i:d2i,...,d1n:d2n]`, but that's not the case for me. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the most efficient way of cropping `A` given `D1` and `D2`.

Comment: What criteria does define which region to crop?

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure if I understand your question. `D1` and `D2` should be two corners of the cropped ndarray.

Comment: You could dynamically put together a list or an array and use that for slicing.

Comment: @Joe can you be so kind to give me an example?

Comment: Google for "advanced indexing numpy", will add an example later if needed.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I had seen, that page, but I will read it again. An example would be appreciated any time possible.

Comment: Does this work?
    `A[tuple(slice(D1[i], D2[i]) for i in range(D1.shape[0]))]`

Comment: @Aaron awesome. this seems to work perfectly. Do you like to write it in a post below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion of the [numpy indexing page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) that @Joe referred to is likely this:

> **Note** 
> Remember that a slicing tuple can always be constructed as obj
>   and used in the `x[obj]` notation. Slice objects can be used in the
>   construction in place of the `[start:stop:step]` notation. For example,
>   `x[1:10:5,::-1]` can also be implemented as:
>  `obj = (slice(1,10,5), slice(None,None,-1))`
> `x[obj]`
>  This can be useful for constructing
>   generic code that works on arrays of arbitrary dimension.

Using this concept you should be able to build your tuple of slices ahead of time then apply it to `A`.

```
obj = tuple(slice(D1[i], D2[i]) for i in range(D1.shape[0]))
A[obj]
```

Note* this is not actually using advanced indexing, as you are still providing a tuple of slice objects which is just the longhand / functional equivalent of using slices separated by colons and commas: `A[d11:d21, ...` Advanced indexing utilizes arrays of different datatypes rather than exclusively tuples of `slice` objects.