# Convolution of NumPy arrays of arbitrary dimension for Cauchy product of multivariate power series

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, convolution, polynomials

I'm trying to implement the idea I have suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877478/cauchy-product-of-multivariate-formal-power-series), for [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of multivariate finite power series (i.e. polynomials) represented as NumPy ndarrays. `numpy.convolve` does the job for 1D arrays, respectively. But to my best knowledge there is no implementations of convolution for arbitrary dimensional arrays. In the above link, I have suggested the equation:

[image]

for convolution of two `n` dimensional arrays `Phi` of shape `P=[p1,...,pn]` and `Psi` of the shape `Q=[q1,...,qn]`, where:

1. `omega`s are the elements of `n` dimensional array `Omega` of the shape `O=P+Q-1`
2. `<A,B>_F` is the generalization of [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) for arbitrary dimensional arrays `A` and `B` of the same shape
3. `A^F` is `A` flipped in all `n` directions
4. `{A}_[k1,...,kn]` is a slice of `A` starting from `[0,...,0]` to `[k1,...,kn]`
5. `Psi'` is `Psi` extended with zeros to have the shape `O` as defined above

I tried implementing the above functions one by one:

```
import numpy as np
```

```
def crop(A,D1,D2):
    return A[tuple(slice(D1[i], D2[i]) for i in range(D1.shape[0]))]
```

as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788969/4999991), slices/crops `A` from `D1` to `D2`,

```
def sumall(A):
    sum1=A
    for k in range(A.ndim):
        sum1 = np.sum(sum1,axis=0)
    return sum1
```

is a generalization of `numpy.sum` for multidimensional ndarrays,

```
def flipall(A):
    A1=A
    for k in range(A.ndim):
        A1=np.flip(A1,k)
    return A1
```

flips `A` is all existing axises, and finally

```
def conv(A,B,K):
    D0=np.zeros(K.shape,dtype=K.dtype)
    return sumall(np.multiply(crop(A,np.maximum(D0,np.minimum(A.shape,K-B.shape)) \
                           ,np.minimum(A.shape,K)), \
                      flipall(crop(B,np.maximum(D0,np.minimum(B.shape,K-A.shape)) \
                           ,np.minimum(B.shape,K)))))
```

where `K=[k1,...,kn]` and for all `0<=kj<=oj`, is a modified version of formula above which only calculate the non-zero multiplications to be more efficient. Now I'm trying to populate the `Omega` array using `fromfunction` or `meshgrid` in combination to  `vectorize` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782224/populating-a-numpy-ndarray-of-an-arbitrary-shape-preferably-without-using-for-l), but I have failed so far. Now my questions in prioritized order are:

- how can I implement the final step and populate the final array in an efficient and pythonic way?
- are there more efficient implementations of the functions above? Or how would you implement the formula?
- is my equation correct? does this represent multiplication of multivariate finite power series?
- haven't really others implemented this before in NumPy or am I reinventing the wheel here? I would appreciate if you could point me towards other solutions.

I would appreciate if you could help me with these questions. Thanks for your help in advance.

**P.S.1** You may find some examples and other information in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/80abba07ea892e50da3df7e318844f33)

**P.S.2** [Here in the AstroPy mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/astropy/2018-August/004440.html) I was told that `scipy.signal.convolve` and/or `scipy.ndimage.convolve` do the job for higher dimensions as well. There is also a `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`. [Here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/astropy/2018-August/004442.html) I have explained why they are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you give some example input and some desired output values?

Comment: @NilsWerner I just saw your comment on [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/80abba07ea892e50da3df7e318844f33) I aded some description and also changed `J` to `K` to be considetant with the orgiinal formula.

Comment: I checked your code, and left some comments. Thanks.

Comment: @NilsWerner I used some parts of your code to update mine. My conv function seems to be ok, the only issue is I don't know how to populate `Omega` using this function.

Comment: Please note that this is not how you should ask questions on SO. It's usually best to ask one concise question at a time, have everything you need in your post, not on other sites, describe the problem as simple as possible, if possible create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without too many optimizations, and have some example input and some desired output data.

Comment: @NilsWerner Thanks for the comment and sorry if my post it not clear enough. I tried my best to be as clear as possible. If you help me know which part is missing or what is not clear I will edit the post.

Comment: Basically all of the above: Get rid of the Gist, provide an MCVE that provably works (maybe only for 1D or 2D, and as simple as possible, yours is too complicated), provide input and output data, and focus on one question.

Comment: @NilsWerner I will write a new post. Thanks.

Comment: @NilsWerner I tried asking the question in a more practical way over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821540/how-to-implement-a-multidimensional-version-of-nympy-convolve). I would appreciate if you could take a look.